# matplotlib pcolor axes scale

Tags: arrays, matplotlib, pandas, heatmap

I have used pcolor to plot a heatmap:

```
df = df.groupby(['d','f'])['beta'].sum()
beta_df = df.unstack('f')
plt.pcolor(beta_df)
```

beta_df is size 35x35, beginning thus:

```
f             0.05      0.06      0.07      0.08      0.09      0.10  ...
d                                                                      
0.050000  0.993125  0.993264  0.991511  0.995148  1.000422  1.003847   
0.105714  0.997931  0.998003  0.997459  1.000743  1.005858  1.001873 
...
```

However, the axes contain integers from 0 to 35 instead of the values of f and d. How to fix it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found this to be the only scale-preserving axes-correction method:

```
    tick_spacing = 10
    plt.yticks(np.arange(0, len(df.index), tick_spacing), df.index[0::tick_spacing])
    plt.xticks(np.arange(0, len(df.columns), tick_spacing), df.columns[0::tick_spacing])
```

Answer (score 4):

First, it is recommended that you use `pcolormesh` instead of `pcolor` (faster and more flexible). You need to tell `pcolormesh` what is the x and y range of your data. This is done by calling it with the array of x and y values. Assuming your 2D array is called `c`, you do it like this:

```
plt.pcolormesh(x, y, c)
```

Where `x` is an array with the x values, and `y` with the y values. You need to make sure that the dimensions of `x` and `y` match the shape of `c`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `plt.axis()` method to set your axes values. So I think you should be able to do something like (If I remember my pandas correctly):

```
xmin = beta_df.index.min()
xmax = beta_df.index.max()
ymax = beta_df.max()
ymin = beta_df.min()
```

and then:

```
plt.axis([xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax])
```

Or something similar to that.

Comment: That is not going to work because the `pcolor` does not have the right range.